# How can I achieve this texture result in Blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I've just received a job to make the photorealistic version of this chair. My approach is to model it like how it is made in real life. First I will model the metal frame, and then model the weaved bamboo stripes on top of it. But then how should I achieve the look in the image? I'm thinking of choosing diffferent brown shades for different stripes. Is it realistic? If not, what should I do to achieve that look?

Thank you for your time!

[image: Chair]

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a lot of ways of doing that. You could just UV map the complex geometry. It doesn't seem like overlapping UVs would matter in this case. You could just select parts and project UVs from view how you need them. You can also use multiple UV maps - maybe one for individual straps if they have some texture along the length, another for all of them(for the sides) based on camera views for the smooth bigger darker and lighter patterns.

Comment: Thank you but honestly I don't really understand your words because of my limited knowledge about UV. I'll check back this answer later.

Comment: If you need the detail of the mesh parts representing weaved stems there are a number of tutorials https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+weave

Comment: It is kind of hard to explain in an answer. I would have to make a long tutorial. You need to learn to project UVs on selected geometry from the viewport position (u hotkey in the viewport in edit mode) and specify the correct UV map with UV Map node for different textures. If you are making the strips with curves, curves have an option to generate UVs automatically along the length if you needed the strips to have some sort of texture along their lengths individually. I would recommend watching some tutorials on UV mapping and learning the basic functionality of the process.